# SQL Combine null rows with non null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Due to the way a particular table is written I need to do something a little strange in SQL and I can't find a 'simple' way to do this

**Table**

```
Name   Place     Amount
Chris  Scotland  
Chris            £1  
Amy    England
Amy              £5
```

Output

```
Chris  Scotland  £1
Amy    England   £5
```

What I am trying to do is above, so the null rows are essentially ignored and 'grouped' up based on the Name

I have this working using For XML however it is incredibly slow, is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where MAX would work

```
select 
   Name
   ,Place = Max(Place)
   ,Amount = Max(Amount)
from
   YourTable
group by
   Name
```

Naturally, if you have more than one occurance of a place for a given name, you may get unexpected results.

Comment: Ah no worries at all @Chris

Comment: when doing max against a string is it using the char length to determine the 'max'?

Comment: No, it's using the ASCII conversion ordering though length can come into play here. For example, c comes after b so it would be returned for the max. however, bb would be returned over c. case sensitivity only matters if your collation is case sensitive. This also applies for `order by` on a `varchar` field. You can make a table of random strings and order by it to see how it'd be sorted (and this would also determine he min and max by the first and last row sorted asc)